# Ractive js is not rendering properly in input tag attribute

Tags: jquery, html, mustache, ractivejs

I am trying to generate html with ractive.js like below code

```
{{#each daysInRange}}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label data-toggle="on">
      <input type="checkbox" class="minimal flat-green"  checked="checked" name="{{name}}" value="true"/>
        <span>{{label}}</span>
    </label>
    <input class="timeRange" type="text" name="monday_time"/>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

And below is the code which I am using to pass the data

```js
var daysInRange = [];
var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: '#model-day-time-choice',
  template: '#FF_model_day_time_choice',
  data: { daysInRange : daysInRange }
});

$('#reservation').daterangepicker({}, function(start, end, label) {
  var newValues = [];
  var obj = {};
  for(start; start.diff(end) < 0; start.add(1,'days')){
     newValues.push({'label':start.format('dddd'),'name':start.format('dddd').toLowerCase()});
      if(newValues.length == 7){
        break;
      }
  }
  ractive.set('daysInRange', newValues).then(updateModelUi);
});
```

But it renders as below screen shot
[image]

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong.
I am new in javascript so please sorry for the code quality.

Thanks

Comment: `Ractive.js` is probably not the most beginner friendly framework out there, so I'd like to suggest an alternative: http://vuejs.org/ (similar structure, better documentation, active development)

Comment: Hey, how did this work out for you mate?

Comment: @ArnarYngvason I am using simple jquery to build this repeat as I was out of time to complete this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `checked` attribute should be `boolean`, or the field, "bound by the `name` attribute".
2. You need to use [Decorators](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/decorators) for jQuery plugins.

#### From the Ractive manual:

> #### Checkboxes
>
> Checkboxes are used to flag a property as true or false. Rather than
>   binding the value attribute, we bind the checked attribute:
>
> ```
> <label>
>   <input type='checkbox' checked='{{on}}'>
>   The lights are {{ on ? 'on' : 'off' }}
> </label>
> ```
>
> (True HTML nerds will recognise that boolean attributes such as
>   checked don't have a value, as such - they either exist on an element
>   or they don't. This makes life unnecessarily difficult; Ractive treats
>   dynamic (i.e., controlled by a mustache) boolean attributes as present
>   if the mustache is true, absent if false.)
>
> Checkboxes may also be bound by the name attribute, which will result
>   in the value specified in the name attribute containing an array of
>   selected checkbox values.
>
> ```
> {{#colors}}
>   <label>
>     <input type='checkbox' name='{{selected}}' value='{{.}}' />{{.}}
>   </label>
> {{/}}
> ```
>
> If colors is an array, `['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue']`, then
>   checking the first box will result in selected becoming `['Red']`.
>   Checking the third box will result in selected becoming `['Red',
>   'Green']`. The array may also be updated from code using set or any of
>   the array modification methods available to Ractive, and the
>   checkboxes will be updated to reflect the contents of the array in the
>   Ractive viewmodel.
>
> Note that checkboxes may be bound by either checked or name but not
>   both.
>
> #### Decorators
>
> A decorator is a simple way to add behaviour to a node **when it is rendered**, or to augment it in some way. Decorators are a good way to teach Ractive tricks from other libraries, such as jQuery UI.

### An example `View` with `decorator` using [`bootstrap-datepicker`](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker) and `moment.js`:

```
var RactiveView = Ractive.extend({
  decorators: {
    dateRangePicker: function(node, fromField, toField) {
      var ractive = node._ractive.root  // A reference to our view instance
      var now = moment()

      $(node).daterangepicker({ranges: {
        'Today': [now, now],
        'Yesterday': [now.subtract(1, 'days'), now.subtract(1, 'days')],
        'Last 7 Days': [now.subtract(6, 'days'), now],
        'Last 30 Days': [now.subtract(29, 'days'), now],
        'This Month': [now.startOf('month'), now.endOf('month')],
        'Last Month': [now.subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'),
                       now.subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
      }}, function(start, end) {
        if(fromField != null && toField != null) {
          ractive.set(fromField, start.format('DD.MM.YYYY'))
          return ractive.set(toField, end.format('DD.MM.YYYY'))
        }
      })

      return {teardown: function() {
        $(node).data('daterangepicker').remove()
      }}
    }
  }
})
```

#### Usage:

```
var myView = new RactiveView({
  data: {
    date: {
      from: null,
      to: null
    }
  }
})
```

#### Template:

```
<div decorator="dateRangePicker: 'date.from', 'date.to'"></div>
```

This is an edited example from one of my projects. Hopefully it will help you
into the right direction.